# What does boolean isStepCountPresent = (flag & 0x01) != 0 mean in java?

Tags: java

I am having troubles understanding this line of code:

```
else{
   something();
   byte flag = data[0];
   boolean isStepCountPresent = (flag & 0x01) != 0; //this line here
   stufToDo();
}
```

Comment: What does `&` do? What does `0x01` mean? Questions you could easily answer with a little research.

Comment: It's just another way to see if the flag is even or odd.  But it's probably being used as a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flag & 0x01) != 0`

`&` is the bit operation and select only the lowest bit in the integer `flag`.

In your example `flag` is the integer value with 32 (amount of bits in `int`) switchers (i.e. `boolean` values).

`boolean isStepCountPresent = (flag & 0x01) != 0;`

You should treat it as: `isStepCountPresent` only if a bit `0` is set in the integer `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

It performs a logical AND on the flag value with 1, that means that the result will be 1 if the last binary digit is also 1.